# How to localize database strings when using XLIFF in Xcode

Tags: ios, database, xcode, localization, xliff

I'm trying to localize my app by using the 'Export for localization...' option in Xcode (v7.0.1). This export takes care of all localized string in my storyboard and code. However I am using a database and one of the fields in this database contains a colorname that needs to be localized. I've no clue how to localized these strings, because Xcode has no knowledge about the strings to be localized.

What do I have to do to add the database strings to the xliff-file that is exported?

Answer (score 0):

You can have some kind of method with switch statement in your code, that could look something like this:

```
static NSString *const RED_COLOR = @"RED_COLOR";
static NSString *const BLUE_COLOR = @"BLUE_COLOR";
static NSString *const MISSING_COLOR = @"MISSING_COLOR";

- (NSString *)localizedColor:(NSString *)color {
    switch (color) {
        case RED_COLOR:
            return NSLocalizedString(RED_COLOR, @"red color for figure");
        case BLUE_COLOR:
            return NSLocalizedString(BLUE_COLOR, @"red color for figure");
        default:
            return NSLocalizedString(MISSING_COLOR, @"color missing");
    }
}
```

You could pass to this method color name that your database returns. You would need to translate all possible color names that can be in your database in your `.strings` file.

Comment: I already tried something like this. The problem is that the export for the XLIFF-file, does not add RED_COLOR to the localizable.strings file. This only works when I use 'return NSLocalizedString("Red", @"red color for figure");' in code. I don't want to specify the same constant string twice in the code.

Comment: Did you try to use `genstrings` ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html)) for creating content of `.strings` files? Or replace `const` with `#define`?

Comment: I'm using swift and not obj-c, but I do not think that matters much. I'm new to the XLIFF-export. It was my understanding that I don't need to use `genstrings` anymore when using XLIFF-export and the `.strings` files are taking care of in the XLIFF-import proces. Did I understand that wrong?

Comment: `genstrings` searches your source code for `NSLocalizedString` macro. Generally this tool was designed to work with Objective-C, but it works with Swift too. You can use it like this in your project directory `find . -name \*.swift | xargs genstrings -o .`. `genstrings` creates the `.strings` files and then you can use Xcode's XLIFF-export to get XLIFF file from `.strings` files.